# Wondering if the use of the word "gotta" is correct here

Tags: meaning

You gotta be very angry.

From an American movie.

My intuation is that is to say **you are really very angry** or **it seems you are angry**.

Why the guy used **gotta** here. **gotta** implies force, like saying **you have to be very angry** that means ** you do not have any other choices**

I have my doubts if the speaker ment something like that!

Comment: 'Have got to' has both the meanings you mention (as does 'must'): You must / gotta try harder, Joe! // You must / You've got to feel devastated, your team being beaten 7 - 0. >> I assume 'gotta' can be used in place of 'have got to' in both senses; it's uncommon here in Britain.

Comment: @Edwin, absolutely it can. The most common expression I can think of where _gotta_ is used in this sense is, “Oooh, that's gotta hurt/sting/burn/etc.”.

Answer (score 4):

Just like *must*, *gotta* (and longer forms, such as *have got to*) may be used in an *epistemic* sense relating to logical inference:

> You gotta be angry =
>   I infer [*perhaps from your demeanour or intonation or from your foregoing narrative—this is not specified*], with a high degree of certainty, that you are angry.

It is not the addressee who is “compelled” to suffer the passion described but the  the speaker who is “compelled” to draw this conclusion.

Comment: Yes, it's interesting to consider how other modals pattern in this sentence: _You hafta be angry, You must be angry, You should be angry, You oughta be angry_ are usable in different situations, with different inferences about how the conclusion was reached by the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without more context, but I read that as:

> You would have to be very angry [... to do something only an angry
>   person would do].

So, rather than forcing or commanding, the speaker is speculating about the subject's mind-state.

If the full context is something like:

> A: They blew up Bob's house!
>
> B: You gotta be very angry to do something like that.

Then rendering the sentence in more formal English would produce something like:

> B: You would have to be very angry to do something like that.

*(This is paraphrasing, as StoneyB points out. It's not the only interpretation that makes sense, by any means.)*

Comment: Good call, you're right. Adjusted to make that clearer,.

Answer (score -1):

Since you use the word "correct" in your title we do need to say that "gotta" is not "correct" English in any context. The "correct" English expression is "have got to".

Comment: *You gotta* is entirely "correct" in US colloquial registers, and the spelling is a "standard" symbolization of colloquial speech.

Comment: We could debate what, if anything, “correct” means with regard to language. As I said, it is not I who brought up the question of correctness.