# meaning and use of "gotta"

Tags: meaning, expressions, contractions

I often heard people say the word "gotta". I have read in this web site that
gotta is a contraction of "I have got to" and that that phrase means "must",
is my understanding correct?

Regarding the use of "gotta", what does the following phrase mean:

1. I gotta get something

thanks.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. You sentence means "I must get something", or "I must procure possession of an as yet unidentified object".

Comment: excuse me for this basic question, the object should be unidentified?

Comment: That was just a description of "something" ;)

Comment: related [How often do people say “gotta”, “wanna” or “gonna” in English speaking countries?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62045/how-often-do-people-say-gotta-wanna-or-gonna-in-english-speaking-countrie/62057#62057) and [Wondering if the use of the word “gotta” is correct here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167814/wondering-if-the-use-of-the-word-gotta-is-correct-here)

Comment: "I have got to..." should properly be contracted to "I've gotta", although in speech the "'ve" could get swallowed to sound like just "I gotta" and over time this has probably become the convention. Of course, the word "got" is entirely redundant in this sentence and the phrase "I have to" on its own means "I must", as you originally suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

The 'particle' (I do not know the correct term for a word used like this) *got* can be used in conjunction with the modal verb *to have to*, as per your example, and also the verb *to have* (in the sense of possession), when used in the present-perfect.

According to [Oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gotta) and [The Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gotta), in addition to the meaning given in your example, *gotta* also serves as a contraction for the conjunction of *have* and *got* in the sense of being in possession, e.g. 'I have got a secret to tell you' can become 'I gotta a secret to tell you'.

For what it's worth, as a native speaker of British English, I would use *gotta* in both of these senses in informal spoken language, but for some reason I would only ever use it in informal(!), *written* contexts as a contraction for the modal *to have to*, i.e. while I would write 'I gotta go', for example in a text message, I would never write 'I gotta new jacket'. I do not know if this is typical of my dialect, or just something personal, though I suspect it's the former.

I would not use *gotta* in any formal context, neither as a contraction for *to have* nor for *to have to*.

As an aside, it is of course possible to use 'I have got to' with the verb 'to get', e.g.

> I have got to get a new car!

The pronunciation can be contracted to the audibly pleasing

> I've gotta getta new car!

Comment: Tangentially, does anybody know the name of the rapid, 'ricocheting' audible effect heard when pronouncing 'gotta getta'? It's sorta similar to rolling an R :)

Comment: really helpful comment, I was always afraid to ask these kind of question before!

Comment: @armando I'm pleased to help! My original wording for my last example ('gotta getta') was misleading, so please take a look at my revision if you found that bit interesting :)

Comment: I find the second usage as in "I gotta secret..." just sounds like sloppy rendering of the verbal "I've got a..." - it's the I have that is contracted to I've, the two words "got a" remain untouched.

Comment: I agree with you @AdamV that it's sloppy, but it's a spelling apparently common enough to warrant its own entry in the sources I linked to, and I think it's really the same thing with the *gotta* in 'I've gotta go home': a verbal contraction is being transcribed into the spelling.